# existence of an inner product making an endomorphism symmetrical

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ a $\mathbb R$- space of finite dimension. Let $u\in L(E)$ diagonalizable and $F$ a sub-space of E stable by $u$.
Show that it exists an inner product on $E$ so that $u$ is a symmetrical endomorphism.

Any hint to begin the resolution ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that an $u \in L(E)$ is symmetric with respect to an inner product, iff the matrix of $u$ with respect to an orthonormal base is symmetric. If $u$ is diagonalizable, there is a basis $B$ of $E$ such that the matrix of $u$ with respect to $B$ is diagonal (hence: symmetric). Now define the inner product such that $B$ is an orthonormal base. Hint: Use coordinates with respect to $B$.

Comment: Is $F$ really needed ?

Comment: Do not think so.